# JSP y Servlet Modelo amigos

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, jpa

estoy desarrollando una red social para una asignatura de la universidad, y tengo un problema con los Amigos. Lo que quiero hacer es un modelo ER en el que, si el Usuario A quiere ser Amigo del Usuario B, le manda una solicitud de amistad. En caso de aceptarla, se crea la relación Amistad tanto de A a B, como de B a A. Mi problema es que no se muy bien cómo modelar esto.

Hasta ahora tengo hecho esto, pero me falla cuando creo una Amistad, siendo que si A es amigo de B y se listan los amigos de A, sale B sin problema, pero cuando listo los amigos de B, sale el propio B como amigo suyo, en vez de A.

Os dejo el modelo ER y una clase prueba que tengo para añadir amigos:

[image: Comentaros también que en Amigos, en el campo IdUsuario (cuando lo paso a NetBeans y me genera las entidades con JPA) se almacena un Usuario en vez de una Id tipo INT.]

```
Usuario senan = usuarioFacade.find(4);
    Usuario tres = usuarioFacade.find(3);

    List<Amigos> listaSenan = senan.getAmigosList();

    Amigos amigoSenan = new Amigos();

    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

    amigoSenan.setFechaInicio(sqlDate);
    amigoSenan.setIdUsuario(tres);
    listaSenan.add(amigoSenan);

    usuarioFacade.edit(senan);
    amigosFacade.edit(amigoSenan);

    RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deberías poner el código de tu entidades: Usuario, Amigos... y cómo compruebas quién es amigo de quién. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] para comprender qué tipo de preguntas se consideran *bien hechas* y cómo tener un [mcve] ayuda a entender tu problema

Answer (score 0):

creo que falta información en tus diagramas, no veo claro como asocias a un amigo de otro, te anexo una imagen con las entidades que creo que podrían ayudarte tomando como base lo que ya hiciste.

En la entidad Amigos agregue idUsuario que es el propio usuario, y se le asocia un usuario amigo, cuando se haga la consulta deberias poder consultar todos los usuarios filtrando por el atributo idUsuario.

Por ejemplo:

- idUsuario: 1 tiene un idAmigoUsuario: 2
- idUsuario: 1 tiene un idAmigoUsuario: 3
- idUsuario: 1 tiene un idAmigoUsuario: 20
- idUsuario: 1 tiene un idAmigoUsuario: 111

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso, la relación entre usuario y amigos seria de uno a muchos no? (Un usuario tiene muchos amigos). Además, si un usuario A se hace amigo del usuario B, habria que añadir los pares (A,B) y (B,A) en amigos no?

Comment: A si es, agregas por pares, recuerda hay muchas formas de modelar un mismo problema, el que veas un modelo no significa que sea la unica forma, todo depende como veas tu el problema y de si tu solucion sirve para representar o resolver lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás pudieras cambiar Amigos por Relaciones.

Relaciones tendría (fechaInicio, idUsuario, idAmigo).

Cambiarías este método a recibir parámetro:

```
List<Amigos> getAmigosList(int idUsuario);
```

También cambiarias Amigos a Relaciones. Pudieras tener este constructor:

```
public Relaciones(Date fecha, int idUsuario, int idAmigo);
```

Si Relaciones fuera una tabla, también evitarías crear dos registros para una amistad.

Comment: Para listar los amigos del usuario A, tendria q mirar las filas en las q es idUsuario y las filas en las q es idAmigo dependiendo de si ha mandado o no la solicitud de amistad no?

Comment: Podrías tener dos campos en la tabla Relaciones: FechaDeSolicitud y FechaDeAceptacion, para usar esa tabla para las solicitudes. O También pudieras hacer otra tabla que se llame Solicitudes y mantener ahí las que no se han confirmado.